# Предлагаю ввести метки "коммуникация", а также связанные с нею метки "точность", "ясность" и "логичность"

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, метки

Ряд речевых ошибок обусловлен не отступлением от правил нормативной грамматики, но  нарушением базовых коммуникативных требований: точности, ясности, логичности (см.:Мучник Б. С. Человек и текст: основы культуры письменной речи. – М.: Книга, 1985., а также: Мучник Б.С. Культура письменной речи: Формирование стилистического мышления. Пособие для учащихся 10-11-х классов средн. школ, гимназий. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. – М.: Аспект Пресс, 1996). Для более точной квалификации причин речевых ошибок и указания способов их исправления, как мне кажется, целесообразно ввести вышеуказанные метки.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на то, что метки создаются самими пользователями, когда возникает необходимость. Привилегия, позволяющая делать это, автоматически выдается по достижении 150 баллов репутации.

Подробнее — в Справке: https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags.